# javascript on href disabeld on apps?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Suddenly all my apps does not work the javascript I include in href, sample:

```
<a href="javascript:dosomething()">click</a>
```

this worked ok a week a go but now it does not execute anyway. is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="#" onClick="dosomething(); return false;">click</a>
```

Comment: It's `onclick` and `javascript:` doesn't belong in there (the only reason why it works is because `xyz:` is a label and thus pretty much a no-op)

Answer (score 0):

you could use onclick instead of href

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">Click1</a>   
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">Click2</a>   
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:doSomething();return false;">Click3</a>   
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">Click4</a>   
<a href="###" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">Click5</a>
```

Comment: Same thing here: `javascript:` doesn't belong into an attribute which only contains javascript anyway - the only place where it is acceptable is in a `href` attribute (and in that case you'd have to ensure that the called function doesn't return anything)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue as well, not sure what is causing it. Because we use ASP.NET link buttons render using the href, and therefore don't post back. Adding the following code turnes an href into an onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

__onclick = function() {
  eval(this._js);
}

__evalLinks = function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1) return;

  var oLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0;i<oLinks.length;i++) {
    if(!oLinks[i].onclick && oLinks[i].href.length > 11 && oLinks[i].href.substr(0, 11) == "javascript:") {
      oLinks[i].onclick = __onclick;
      oLinks[i]._js = unescape(oLinks[i].href.substr(11, oLinks[i].href.length-11));
    }
  }
}

window.onload = __evalLinks;
</script>
```

Many Thanks,
Ady